Not able to get current auditor id using keycloak in spring boot
i am using java 21, spring security 6 and keycloak version 22.0.4. Here i am trying to use audit aware to enable timestamps and records who created and updated. But the problem is i am getting currunt auditor id as null.
"Message": "Disability created successfully",
    "HttpStatus": "OK",
    "Data": {

type here

        "id": "388465a1-f06b-4d28-acbb-9110f8905ce3",
        "effectiveFrom": null,
        "deletedAt": null,
        "createdDate": "2024-05-14T16:49:17.655439",
        "createdBy": null,
        "lastModifiedDate": "2024-05-14T16:49:17.655439",
        "lastModifiedBy": null,
        "branchId": "395d5596-af9f-4acf-bcc5-89471098a24f",
        "name": "uyu problem",
        "notes": "Additional notes about the disability"
    }

response from the create request in postman
i am expecting loged in user id in this created by
i am using getCurrunt auditor method
 @Override
    public Optional<UUID> get Current Auditor() {
        Authentication authentication =
                SecurityContextHolder
                        .getContext()
                        .getAuthentication();

        if (authentication == null ||
                !authentication.isAuthenticated() ||
                authentication instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken) {
            System.out.println("Authentication is null or not authenticated");
            return Optional.empty();
        }

        Object principal = authentication.getPrincipal();

        if (principal instanceof User userPrincipal) {
            System.out.println("Auditing for user: " + userPrincipal.getUsername());
            return Optional.ofNullable(userPrincipal.getId());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Principal is not a User entity: " + principal);
            return Optional.empty();
        }

i have tried some ways to figure it out but can not able to get the desired results
i have addded a bean in the security config file
`@Bean
    public AuditorAware<UUID> auditorAware() {
        return new ApplicationAuditAware();
    }
//my entity class

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "UUID")
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private UUID id;

    /** Date and time when the record was effective from. */
    @Column(name = "effective_from")
    private Date effectiveFrom;

    /** Deleted At timestamp when the record was deleted. Otherwise null */
    @Column(
            name = "deleted_at",
            insertable = false
    )
    private LocalDateTime deletedAt;

    /**
     * The timestamp when the entity was created.
     */
    @CreatedDate
    @Column(
            name = "created_date",
            nullable = false,
            updatable = false
    )
    private LocalDateTime createdDate;

    /**
     * The timestamp when the entity was last updated.
     */
    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(
            name = "last_modified_date",
            insertable = false
    )
    private LocalDateTime lastModifiedDate;

    /**
     * The user who created the entity.
     */
    @CreatedBy
    @Column(
            name = "created_by",
           // nullable = false,
            updatable = false
    )
    private UUID createdBy;

    /**
     * The user who last updated the entity.
     */
    @LastModifiedBy
    @Column(
            name = "last_modified_by",
            insertable = false
    )
    private UUID lastModifiedBy;

}`

i am still getting the same output which is not desired output
